# Execute javascript code after asynchronous function return

Tags: javascript, callback, return

I have a function that looks like this:

```
function arvfl($content, config) {
    if(this instanceof arvfl) {  /* called with new */
        this.id = arvfl.id++;
        this.setup($content, config);
        this.chainCallbacks(arvfl._callbackChain);
    } else {
        var fl = new arvfl($content, config);
        fl.open();
        //alert("123");
        return fl;
    }
}
```

The code that calls the function looks like this:

```
$.arvfl = arvfl;
doSomething()
```

I want the function `doSomething()` to execute after arvfl returns the value. Even if I create a callback to pass to arvfl function I'll still not be able to execute it after the return statement.

This way as the code is written, doSomething() executes before arvfl returns value. I don't want that.

Comment: Pass `doSomething` as callback to `arvfl`. Of course `arvfl` also has to call that callback. But in your example, `$.arvfl = arvfl;` isn't calling `arvfl` at all, so it's unclear what the actual flow is.

Comment: You need to pass `doSomething` as an argument into the `arvfl` function.

Comment: But, that way I would still execute doSomething before return fl,right? I want doSomething executed after return fl

Comment: Your callback does not execute before `arvfl` returns a value. It will however execute before the asynchronous code is complete. You simply *can not* execute `doSomething()` in that position and have it wait for the async code. If you could, then the could wouldn't be async. The info you provided is incomplete, but it looks like there's some sort of handling for callbacks. If so, then that's your solution.